# how to get a numpy array from frequency and indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
nparr = np.asarray([[u'fals', u'nazi', u'increas', u'technolog', u'equip', u'princeton', 
                     u'realiti', u'civilian', u'credit', u'ten'],
                    [u'million', u'thousand', u'nazi', u'stick', u'visibl', u'realiti', 
                     u'west', u'singl', u'jack', u'charl']])
```

What I need to do is to calculate the frequency of each item, and have another numpy array with the corresponding frequency of each item in the same position.

So, here as my array shape is `(2, 10)`. I need to have a numpy array of shape `(2, 10)` but with the frequency values. Thus, the output of the above would be:

```
[[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

What I have done so far:

```
unique, indices, count = np.unique(nparr, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
```

Though in this way the count is the frequency of unique values and it does not give me the same shape as the original array.

Comment: You have a missing quote, which SO's code markup makes very easy to find and fix

Comment: @MadPhysicist I didnt get you, whats the missing quote!

Comment: `u'realiti` is missing a quote

Comment: Oops Thanks for mentioning that @yatu. updated.

Comment: No worries. I've poseted a much simpler answer. You were off because you want the inverted index, not the raw index.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need this particular output shape/style?

Comment: Actually, this is tiny part of a new framework for topic modeling. I need to keep the shape of the array for the following operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `return_inverse` rather than `return_index`:

```
_, i, c = np.unique(nparr, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

`_` is a convention to denote discarded return values. You don't need the unique values to know where the counts go.

You can get the counts arranged in the order of the original array with a simple indexing operation. Unraveling to the original shape is necessary, of course:

```
c[i].reshape(nparr.shape)
```

Comment: Didn't think of using `return_inverse` here, certainly makes it simpler

Comment: @yatu. The trick is `return_inverse`. I think that argument was added just for this sort of problem.

Comment: Inverse I meant yes. Knew of it, just for some reason `searchsorted` came to my mind :)

Comment: Tahnks it is simpler.